# How to to differentiate between a string with (parsable) date format and a stringified float number?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

there is a string "05/05/2022" how to check that it can be a date, but "5.1" should not be a date
Date example

```
05.05.2020
05/05/2020
05/05/2020;22:40
```

an example of not a date but a numbers

```
5
5.1
5.23
```

Comment: You want to check line by line, right?

Comment: You just want to check that it is in the right format? You need complex solution that is an actual date.

Comment: This regex pattern will check only d/m/Y or m/d/Y where year is 4 ditigs. `(\d{1,2})([\.\/])(\d{1,2})([\.\/])(\d{4})`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a regex like ...

1. [`/^\d{1,2}(?<separator>[./])\d{1,2}\k<separator>\d{2}(?:\d{2})?(?:\s*;\s*\d{2}:\d{2})?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/6CwyXy/1) ... or ...
2. [`/^\d{2}(?<separator>[./])\d{2}\k<separator>\d{4}(?:\s*;\s*\d{2}:\d{2})?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/6CwyXy/2)

... where the former is more forgiving with the date format in terms of digit count of day(`1` or `2`), month(`1` or `2`) and year(`2` or `4`) whereas the latter enforces a strict digit count of `2,2,4` for e.g. `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Both patterns utilize a [named capturing group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) for the date separator (either `.` or `/`) which will be used as [named backreference](https://javascript.info/regexp-backreferences#backreference-by-name-k) in order to ensure a correct date format.

Both patterns also feature the optional match for a time format ... [`(?:\s*;\s*\d{2}:\d{2})?`] ... which might possibly follow a valid date format.

```js
const multilineSample =
`5.5.20
5.5.202
5.5/2020
05.05.2020
05/05.2020
05/05/2020
05/05/2020;22:40

5
5.1
5.23`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/6CwyXy/1]
const regXDateFormatLooseDigitCount =
  /^\d{1,2}(?<separator>[./])\d{1,2}\k<separator>\d{2}(?:\d{2})?(?:\s*;\s*\d{2}:\d{2})?$/gm;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/6CwyXy/2]
const regXDateFormatStrictDigitCount =
  /^\d{2}(?<separator>[./])\d{2}\k<separator>\d{4}(?:\s*;\s*\d{2}:\d{2})?$/gm

console.log(
  'sample data ...\n',
  multilineSample
);
console.log(
  'result for loose digit count ...',
  multilineSample.match(regXDateFormatLooseDigitCount)
);
console.log(
  'result for strict digit count ...',
  multilineSample.match(regXDateFormatStrictDigitCount)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Very cool! I've used named capturing groups with `groups.group` and replacements `$<group>`, but didn't know about `\k<group>` backreferences within the pattern itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you'll be only getting numbers or date and nothing other than these two inputs :

```js
// Assuming that you'll be getting either a date or a number
let checkDate = (val)=>{
  let count = 0 ;

  for(let i=0 ; i<val.length ; i++)if(val[i]==='.'||val[i]==="/")count++;
  if(count<=1)return false;
  return true;
}
let date1 = "05/05/2022";
if(checkDate(date1))console.log(date1+" is a date");
else console.log(date1+" is a number");
let date2 = "5.34";

if(checkDate(date2))console.log(date2+" is a date");
else console.log(date2+" is a number");
```

Comment: How about `"05/05/2022"` then, instead of `"05.05.2022"`?

Comment: How about `"5/5.22"` as `date1` and "`5/34`" as `date2`?